# Two "access codes" instead of "username" and "password"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authentication

The information system I sometimes use has 2 access codes that are password-masked.

Is this just a security through obscurity measure (being able to punch in username and password in front of audience) or does it have any other advantage over the conventional user/pass or token/secred?

I'm considering this when building my own IS for my business partners and myself. Is this any good or just annoying and useless unmemorable stuff for the user?

If it is a good idea, how to implement that with `user.authenticate()`?

Comment: Do you have any context about which authentication system you may use, or will you roll your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would *not* implement such a system, because..

- The username/ID (first "access code") *need not be a secret*; while it should not expose confidential information (defined by policy), the purpose of this key is *not* to "add security" and making it hard to remember would annoy people - at least, it would annoy me.

  If a user has to write down a "secret" because it is too hard to remember .. then anyone with access to the recording (e.g. text file, Post-It note) has access to the  might-not-be-a-secret secret.
- The way to increase security with passwords (second "access code") is to *encourage passphrases*, which are can be *easier* than "P@ssw0rds!" to remember (and are *much* easier than random passwords to remember!), but [*much harder* to brute-force](http://xkcd.com/936/). It is the password/pass-phrase which is the secret token.

  Assuming the use of proper *connection encryption* and using sound bcrypt/scrypt *password hashing* (and not suffering from an attack vector such as Heartbleed or a local keysniffer), then the next consideration is to *mitigate brute-force* attacks.

I would focus on using a solid (*exiting and proven*) authentication implementation, and secure server management and key policy.

That being said, here are additional thoughts ..

- It might be useful/relevant to make the username/ID (first "access code") field *masked*, like a password field. This *can* prevent cases where the password/pass-phrase is accidentally exposed when entered into a username/ID field, as when such authentication is done in front of a live audience. (I've seen this mistake done several times.)

  However the goal is *not* to add security, excepting that it can mitigate accidents, as the username/ID is *not* a password: it is *not* "encrypted", hashed, or otherwise considered a secret.
- Using an additional credential provider (e.g. RSA fob, or smart card/fingerprint/pub-private keys) can be used in such cases where increased security is required. Appropriate use of such is *much* more secure than "two passwords".

Comment: Thank you. I will just mask the username field as well and use the existing and proven solution :)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of security, `access codes` are probably slightly more secure than `user` & `pass`, considering they're encrypted correctly. This is my opinion

For Rails, you will have to remember 3 important factors:

1. Who's using your system
2. How will they engage with the authentication area
3. Are you using with any other system (such as `Devise`)?

--

**Public Keys**

If you're looking to create a `preview` mode of sorts, I would create a series of `API` keys, which you'll be able to use to gain limited functionality to the app.

We do that like this:

```
#users table
id | public_key | other | information | created_at | updated_at

#app/models/concerns/token.rb
module Token
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
       before_create :generate_token
    end

    protected

    def generate_token
        self.public_key = loop do
           random_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(10, false)
           break random_token unless self.class.exists?(public_key: random_token)
        end
    end
 end

 #app/models/user.rb
 include Token
```

I found this code somewhere (I forgot where unfortunately), but it basically uses the [`before_create`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) callback to populate the `public_key` attribute of your `User` model.

The public key is created using the [`SecureRandom`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) method